# Firebase adding same keys always no error

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have android project. I am using Firebase database for chat room in my app.

I have a function to create user, in this function I added all new users as **key**, not value to make it unique. No problem, I can not add new user if I try to add new user with existing name.

But I am **always** getting **null** error although I try to add new user with same name. I think I should get error if I try to add new user with same name.

**createUser:**

```
private void createUser(final String uname){
    DatabaseReference dbref = firedb.getReference();

    final String testedUname = uname ;
    dbref.child("User").child(uname).setValue(true, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError error, DatabaseReference ref) {

            if (error != null) {

               Log.d("firebaseTest","tested_uname: " + testedUname + " Data could not be saved. " + error.getMessage());
               requestNewUser();
            } else {

                Log.d("firebaseTest","tested_uname: " + testedUname + " Data saved successfully." );

                //Always, this else statement works although I write same username.
            }

        }
    });
}
```

I added new 5 values.

> Aaabbb
>
> Aaabbb(!)
>
> Aabbcc
>
> Aa11aa
>
> Aabbcc(!)

I think in 2nd and 5th line the code should give output when these text are existing in database:

> Data could not be saved.

But it always give output:

> Data saved successfully.

```
05-22 14:32:20.346 13402-13402/xxx D/firebaseTest: tested_uname: Aaabbb Data saved successfully.
05-22 14:32:34.666 13402-13402/xxx D/firebaseTest: tested_uname: Aaabbb Data saved successfully.
05-22 14:32:51.176 13402-13402/xxx D/firebaseTest: tested_uname: Aabbcc Data saved successfully.
05-22 14:33:06.026 13402-13402/xxx D/firebaseTest: tested_uname: Aa11aa Data saved successfully.
05-22 14:33:22.826 13402-13402/xxx D/firebaseTest: tested_uname: Aabbcc Data saved successfully.
```

[final database in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPzIR.png)

As a result, my *CompletionListener* always returns null for error variable.

How can I prevent to return null if there is existing user in the database?

Comment: Data will be replaced everytime, whether the key exists or not!

Comment: So how can I solve this problem? In fact I tracked database after adding same users there is no color like green or yellow.

Comment: Before adding a user check if the user exists.

Comment: In fact I was checking then adding but this cause big performance problem if number of users exceeds 10K

Comment: If this is a case where only add/delete is possible and not update/change you can use [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#existing_data_vs_new_data)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("User").child(uname);
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

         if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            // User already exists       
        } else {
            //CreateUser()
        }
    }
}
```